# Repeat a RelativeLayout n times

Tags: android

How I can repeat a RelativeLayout n times, in a scrollable list?
I mean I want to create a list of relative layouts those number can be modified during the program execution.

Comment: That's what ListView is for. Have you looked into ListView?

Comment: Yup, I know. But I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) instead. Create a class which extends [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) and in getView() of this class create the view you want to repeat n times. Add this class as adapter for ListView. And by using ListView you dont even have to use ScrollView. ListView takes care of everything.

Comment: Yes there are many examples you can find on various sites like http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/ or http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html or http://hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-items-row/ or just search listview with custom view on google you will find many